# Flutter Bloc and Http Library bloc state not updating

Tags: flutter, bloc

I use `bloc 8.0.1` and `http ^0.13.4`.

When you run the application, only the `WeatherInitial()` status appears on the screen. I can't see other states. `debugPrint("debug3");` I can't see the line of code in console. The try catch doesn't go inside the line of code. Can you find out what the problem is?

**BLOC**

```
class WeatherBloc extends Bloc<WeatherEvent, WeatherState> {
final WeatherRepository repository = locator<WeatherRepository>();

WeatherBloc() : super(WeatherInitial()) {
  on<WeatherEvent>((event, emit) async {
   if (event is FetchWeatherEvent) {
     WeatherLoadingState();
    try {
     final Weather? weather = await repository.getWeather(event.cityName);
      WeatherLoadedState(weather: weather!);
      debugPrint("debug3");
     } catch (_) {
      WeatherErrorState();
    }
   }
  });
  }
}
```

**EVENT**

```
 abstract class WeatherEvent extends Equatable {
 const WeatherEvent();

 @override
 List<Object> get props => [];
 }

 class FetchWeatherEvent extends WeatherEvent {
  final String cityName;

 const FetchWeatherEvent({required this.cityName});
}
```

**State**

```
 abstract class WeatherState extends Equatable {
  const WeatherState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
  }

 class WeatherInitial extends WeatherState {}

 class WeatherLoadingState extends WeatherState {}

 class WeatherLoadedState extends WeatherState {
  final Weather weather;

const WeatherLoadedState({required this.weather});
 }
class WeatherErrorState extends WeatherState {}
```

**Body**

```
 class WeatherApp extends StatelessWidget {
     String? selectedCity;
    @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _weatherBloc = BlocProvider.of<WeatherBloc>(context);
    return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
       title: const Text("WeatherApp"),
        actions: [
       IconButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          selectedCity = await Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => const CityChoose(),
            ),
          );
          if (selectedCity != null) {
            _weatherBloc.add(FetchWeatherEvent(cityName: 
     selectedCity!));
          }
        },
        icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
      ),
     ],
    ),
   body: Center(
    child: BlocBuilder(
      bloc: _weatherBloc,
      builder: (context, WeatherState state) {
        if (state is WeatherInitial) {
          return const Center(
            child: Text("Select City"),
          );
        } 
         if (state is WeatherLoadingState) {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        } 
         if (state is WeatherLoadedState) {
          final weather = state.weather;
          debugPrint(weather.title);
          return ListView(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Center(
                    child: LocationWidget(
                  selectedCity: weather.title,
                )),
              ),
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Center(child: LastUpdateWidget()),
              ),
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Center(child: WeatherImageWiddget()),
              ),
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: Center(child: TemperatureCondition()),
              ),
            ],
          );
        } else {
          return const Center(
            child: Text("Error"),
          );
        }
         },
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Where do you provide WeatherBloc?

Comment: I updated my code in the code under the body header

Comment: Btw you need to add `weather` in your `props` method if you want to emit the same state, but with different `weather`. Otherwise it won't recognize it. Your weather model should also extend from `Equatable` with all of its properties in `props` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `emit` to emit a state in the `Bloc`. `emit` is declared in the closure of `on<T>`.

```
emit(WeatherLoadedState(weather: weather!));
emit(WeatherErrorState());
```

Comment: yes, ıts work, now i see error message on the screen. My code got into catch, what do you think could be the reason?

Comment: What is the error message/StackTrace?

Comment: I am not getting any error. weather doesn't go into bloc try, when I debug it

Comment: Does it go in the `catch` part?

Comment: yes ,  I think there is an error in the getWeather() function

Comment: yeah, you need to debug the code in `getWeather`.